# ¿como muestro una lista enlazada en c por comparacion de strings?

Tags: c, lista, codificación, sintaxis, impresión

Tengo una lista enlazada, la cuál intento mostrarle sus datos de personas. Cuando inserto una persona, muestra todo bien. Cuando cargo dos o mas, y lo muestro, muestra los datos alterados.

Lo que intento hacer es pedir el ingreso de un nombre, y compararlo con el nombre de una persona cargada en la lista, pero cuando se compara los strings, imprime alterado, mostrando los datos de una persona distinta a la ingresada por teclado.

El código que inserta los datos (el cual esta bien pero lo pongo porque igual lo piden) es este:

```
void cargar_datos_varados(personas *P){
    char ape[20],nomb[20];
    printf("Ingrese el apellido\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]s",ape);
    cargar_apellido(P,ape);
    printf("Ingrese el nombre\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]s",nomb);
    cargar_nombre(P,nomb);
}
void cargar_n_personas(listabi *L){
    int a=0,cantp=0;
    personas elem;
    inicializa(&elem);
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de personas a cargar\n");
    scanf("%d",&cantp);
    while(cantp<1){
        printf("Ingrese una cantidad valida\n");
        scanf("%d",&cantp);
    }
    while(a<cantp){
         if(!isfull(*L)){
             cargar_datos_persona(&elem);
             insertar(L,elem);
         }
         else{
             printf("Espacio insuficiente. No se pudo cargar las personas");
         }
         a++;
    }
}
```

El código que la muestra es este:

```
void mostrar_persona(persona P){
        printf("Apellido:%s\n",ver_apellido(P));
        printf("Nombre:%s\n",ver_nombre(P));
}
void mostrar_una_persona(lista L,char apellido[],char nombre[]){
        reset(&L);
        while(!isoos(L)){
            if(strcmp(ver_apellido(copia(L)),apellido)){
                mostrar_persona(copia(L));
            }
            forwards(&L);
        }

}
```

Por último, el tda donde carga los datos antes de pasarlos a la lista:

```
typedef struct
{
    char apellido[30];
    char nombre[30];
    
} personas;
void cargar_apellido(personas *d,char a[])
{
    strcpy((*d).apellido,a);
}
void cargar_nombre(personas *d,char n[])
{
    strcpy((*d).nombre,n);
}
char* ver_apellido(personas d)
{
    char *aux;
    aux=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    if(aux==NULL)
        exit(1);
    else{
        strcpy(aux,d.apellido);
        return aux;
    }
}
char* ver_nombre(personas d)
{
    char *aux1;
    aux1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    if(aux1==NULL)
        exit(1);
    else
    {
        strcpy(aux1,d.nombre);
        return aux1;
    }

}
```

Si alguien me ayuda con esto, le agradecería, ya que me come la cabeza.

Comment: Faltan funciones esenciales en ese código, como `insertar`... pero al añadirlas va a quedar una pregunta excesivamente larga... por favor, intenta elaborar un ejemplo **mínimo** y **completo** que reproduzca el problema

Answer (score 1):

Para comparar cadenas, usa [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) de la cabecera `<string.h>`:

```
char cadena1[] = "Hola";
char cadena2[] = "Mundo";
int comparacion = strcmp(cadena1, cadena2);
```

Si `cadena1` y `cadena2` son iguales, el resultado será `0`, si la primera cadena es "*menor*" (aparecería antes en el diccionario) el resultado será negativo y el resultado será positivo en caso contrario.

Puede que esto ya lo sepas, pero por la manera en que usas `strcmp` en tu código o no lo sabes o estás confundiendo conceptos. La función `strcmp` compara cadenas, así que puedes comparar directamente:

```
int es_la_misma_persona(personas *p, char *apellido, char *nombre){
    return (strcmp(p->apellido, apellido) == 0) && (strcmp(p->nombre, nombre) == 0);
}
```

**NO HAY QUE HACER NINGUNA COPIA** de los valores a comparar, tu código es una bomba de relojería por las copias innecesarias que estás haciendo, las funciones `ver_apellido` y `ver_nombre` son innecesarias, absurdas y generan fugas de memoria. Se pueden substituir por un `printf`:

```
// ver_apellido:
printf("%s", p->apellido);
// ver_nombre:
printf("%s", p->nombre);
```

Por otro lado esas dos funciones reciben un `personas` **POR COPIA**, dado que `personas` es una estructura con punteros internos (`char apellido[30]` y `char nombre[30]`) esa copia funcionará mal, no entiendo por qué en el resto de funciones pasas puntero a `personas` mientras que sólo en esas dos pasas una copia.

Por último, la estructura `personas` guarda **UNA** persona, el nombre debería ser en singular.

Comment: Hola. Se que no se hace un copia al mostrar strings, pero es una implementacion aplicable para el funcionamiento del IDE que uso. @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: Eso es mentira. No se copian cadenas de caracteres para mostrarlas, sea cual sea el IDE. Menos aún se copian para usarlas como parámetro de función y generar fugas de memoria.